# What is the limit to summoning barbarians with a Horn of Valhalla?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

The [Horn of Valhalla](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magicItems/wondrousItems.html#horn-of-valhalla) item in Pathfinder is meant to make barbarians appear and fight for you when you blows it:

> [the horn] appears to be normal until someone speaks its command word and blows the horn. Then the horn summons a number of human barbarians to fight for the character who summoned them. Each horn can be blown just once every 7 days.

However there doesn't seem to be any limit to how long the barbarians are staying with you. Does that mean you can blow the horn every week and just stack a bigger and bigger army of barbarians?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No, they last until slain or an hour passes**

Just below that section you quoted, after the table, is another paragraph

> Summoned barbarians are constructs, not actual people (though they seem to be); they arrive with the starting equipment for barbarians. They attack anyone the possessor of the horn commands them to fight until they or their opponents are slain or until 1 hour has elapsed, whichever comes first.

So, they last at most an hour.